# SQL Server Error When using CASE with GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am getting Error "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference." When running the following query in SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @runDate smalldatetime = GETDATE()
SELECT  @runDate AS RunDate,
    Division, 
    Product ,
    CASE WHEN Score >= 0 AND Score <= 6 THEN 'GOOD'
         WHEN Score IN (7,8) THEN 'EXCELLENT'
         WHEN Score IN (9,10) THEN 'OUTSTANDING'
         ELSE 'INVALID' END AS Rank,
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
    FROM  CurrentAnalysis
    WHERE  TimeStamp  >  @runDate - 1 
           AND  TimeStamp  <=  @runDate
           AND  Source IN ('XXX', 'AAA') 
    GROUP BY  @runDate, 
              Division, Product,
              CASE WHEN Score >= 0 AND Score <= 6 THEN 'GOOD'
                   WHEN Score IN (7,8) THEN 'EXCELLENT'
                   WHEN Score IN (9,10) THEN 'OUTSTANDING'
                   ELSE 'INVALID' END
```

I have given the same CASE in GROUP BY but still getting the same error. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message pertains to the inclusion of the variable in the `group by`, if you remove it, you should be all right:

```
GROUP BY  Division, Product,
          CASE WHEN Score >= 0 AND Score <= 6 THEN 'GOOD'
               WHEN Score IN (7,8) THEN 'EXCELLENT'
               WHEN Score IN (9,10) THEN 'OUTSTANDING'
               ELSE 'INVALID' 
          END
```

Comment: IF i remove the CASE from GROUP BY, then also same error will be the output. How to calculate the aggregate function COUNT without the GROUP By clause???

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't remove the `case`, just the `@runDate`, as my snippet shows. The `case` is not the problem